# How to choose alternative tab to open in Navigation Form in Access using VBA

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have Navigation Form with horizontal and vertical tabs. How do I code to get back to the vertical tab when I click on the horizontal. I do not want to go back to the first vertical tab but to someone who is further down, to the one I left earlier.

Comment: Welcome to SO Peter. Please can you share the code you have tried so far.

Comment: I haven't found anything to test yet. What I want to happen is that when you click on the horizontal tab is to reopen the last used vertical tab and not the top one. This is for the user to avoid an extra click.

Comment: How should Access know which tab you left earlier?

Comment: I store vertical tab data in global variables. A variable for each horizontal tab. Also stores other information needed to recreate what the form look like when it was leaved for another form.

Comment: One thing I discovered is that if you move the vertical tabs, you retain the original first tab that appears when you click on the horizontal tab.